# Does the android application may allow another app to modify own files?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am wondering about new skinning mechanism for my app. However I don't want to make my application bigger.

Is it possible to create another app, which will be able add/change files of another **my app** in /data/data/com.myfirstapp directory ?

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a`ContentProvider` that other apps could use to transfer data to your app, which could then save it to its own data directory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simply no, you can access other applications from your own application but you cannot edit or change them.